# sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.2.0: not found

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt, apache-spark-sql

I am using dependency:

```
version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0"
```

While importing dependency I am getting error

> [error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:
>   org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.2.0: not found*

[image: error while importing dependency]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no scalaVersion `2.2.0` Use `scalaVersion := "2.11.8"`

I guess you are referring to the sparkVersion as `2.2.0`

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
val sparkVersion := "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion
```

Comment: i found you very good in spark !! i started learning spark could you guide me how should i do..

Comment: I am not sure with the proper guide, But If you have knowledge of scala/java/python/R you can easily start Spark. There are lots of tutorials out there